# Relation "has_one" - how to chose elements that have nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Assuming I have a model of Ticket and this Ticket has one issue:

```
has_one :issue, inverse_of: :ticket
```

I need to define a query that choose only Tickets that don't have an issue (has `nil` in it's place).
I tried "includes", I tried "left_joins" but doesn't work. Still got Tickets with issues.
I need something like this (sure it cannot work, but describes what I need):

```
Ticket.where(issue: nil)
```

Comment: Are you using Rails?

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `left_joins` (alias for `left_outer_joins`) for that:

```
Ticket.left_joins(:issue).where(issues: { id: nil })
# SELECT "tickets".*
# FROM "tickets"
# LEFT OUTER JOIN "issues"
# ON "issues"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id"
# WHERE "issues"."id" IS NULL
```